# How to generate user access token from active directory token?

Tags: azure-active-directory, access-token, sharepoint-online

We are using custom web api and angular as a front-end. We already have active directory access token and we need to access SharePoint lists under user context. How to use azure active directory token to generate user access token to access SharePoint on behalf of Flow?

Comment: Why did you want to use active directory token to generate token? You can use ad access token to access sharepoint rest api directly. You can refer to https://www.advaiya.com/blog/access-sharepoint-rest-api-using-oauth/

Comment: We are using custom web api and calling those from angular based front-end application. We need to access sharepoint libraries using user context.

Comment: The short answer is yes, you can exchange the access token you have for a token for another API. You use the on-behalf-of flow to do that.

Comment: Hi Junnas, thank you for your reply. Can you please tell me, how to use it?

Answer (score 0):

To use the acquired access_token to request new access_token from another API, you could use the on_behalf_of flow.

For V2 enpoint, the request URL:

https://login.microsoftonline.com//oauth2/v2.0/token

```
POST /oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Host: login.microsoftonline.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer
&client_id=<application-id>
&client_secret=<key value>
&assertion=<acquired access_token>
&requested_token_use=on_behalf_of
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read email(here the example API is [ms graph API][1], and the permissions are User.Read and email)
```

For the details, you could refer to this [dos](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow#first-case-access-token-request-with-a-shared-secret).

Comment: Hi SunnySun, thanks for your response, but it is not working for me as i am getting unauthorized error.

Comment: We are using app with Azure AD V2 endpoint. In that case what should be the value of scope for SharePoint?

Comment: Yes, in the v2 endpoint, the resource will be replaced by scope, the format for the scope should be `your sharepoint uri/permission`. And I already update the answer for the v2 endpoint, sorry for this inconvenience.

Comment: Great! It could be useful for you.

Comment: And please make a mark for it, so that it could help others, thanks.